# Tips for golfing javascript code, especially converting while loop to expression

Tags: code-golf, tips, javascript

The code:

```
function L(){N=null;E=[N,N];t=this;h=E;t.u=i=>h=[i,h];
t.o=_=>h==E?N:h[+!(h=h[1])];t.e=(i,l)=>h=(l||h)==E?[i, 
E]:[(l||h)[0],t.e(i,(l||h)[1])];t.s=_=>{o="";while(i=t.o())
{o+=i+","}return o}}
```

For my response to this (old) question: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196783/72421 (my linked answer has a commented version of the code and some disclaimers about valid inputs and outputs)

I'm looking for suggestions on how to golf it further. I feel the last function is especially verbose. I managed to make every other function a single expression so I didn't need curly brackets or a return statement, but couldn't figure out how to make the last one not require a while loop.

Comment: As a side note, I think `t.o()` fails if the list contains a `0` (or any other falsy value that may actually appear in the list), because it's treated the same way as a `null`. I assume that you're only asking for a golfed version, bugs included. :) But you may want to clarify this point.

Comment: @Arnauld I mentioned that as a disclaimer on my answer. I'm new, and not sure if that's a violation of the rules. Also wasn't sure if I should copy-paste all that into this question.

Comment: Oh I see. I overlooked the footnote in your answer.

Comment: @Arnauld If someone figured out a better way to do t.o that didn't have that issue (without just replacing `+!`. with an equality test that adds a few bytes) I'd definitely consider that a valid answer to this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the best way to get rid of the curly brackets is to go recursive.

#### Original function (46 bytes)

```javascript
t.s=_=>{o="";while(i=t.o()){o+=i+","}return o}
```

#### Recursive version (29 bytes)

```javascript
t.s=_=>(i=t.o())?i+[,t.s()]:i
```

The `i+[,t.s()]` trick saves a byte over `i+','+t.s()`.

Because you stop when `t.o()` returns `null`, the result of your original version always ends with a comma. In the new version, we actually append `null` at the end (that's the `:i`) but it's coerced to an empty string because of the above trick, leading to the same behavior.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any suggestions for avoiding `h` being a global variable without having to replace every usage with `t.h`?

Comment: @DanielFranklin You can simply declare `function L(h)` (an unused parameter) to put `h` in the local scope. But this is code-golf, so we usually don't worry about that -- unless explicitly specified otherwise but I haven't read the original challenge thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you. Good to know that isn't necessary.

Answer (score 5):

### Shortening `t.s`

#### Favor recursion over while loop

Given your `t.s` function

```javascript
t.s=_=>{o="";while(i=t.o()){o+=i+","}return o}
```

Observe that `o` is a simple accumulator, so we can easily convert the loop into a recursive function. There are several ways to write the recursive function:

```javascript
// explicit accumulator, aka tail-recursion
t.s=(o="")=>(i=t.o())?t.s(o+i+","):o
// implicit accumulator, shorter, saves 15 bytes from OP's code
t.s=_=>(i=t.o())?i+","+t.s():""
```

#### [Free commas](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113405/78410)

`i+","+t.s()` can be shortened to `i+[,t.s()]`, saving 1 byte.

### Shortening the rest

#### Initialize the second parameter of `t.e` to `h`

The function `t.e` is using `(l||h)` several times, just to handle the initial call. JS's default argument is very permissive, so we can do this:

```javascript
// instead of
t.e=(i,l)=>h=(l||h)==E?[i,E]:[(l||h)[0],t.e(i,(l||h)[1])];
// do this
t.e=(i,l=h)=>h=l==E?[i,E]:[l[0],t.e(i,l[1])];
```

#### Simplify base case

Instead of `E=[N,N]`, simply `E=[]` works too. This has several golfing opportunities regarding string coercion:

- `h==E` is equivalent to `h==[]`, and `[]` coerces to `""`. Anything that stringifies into something other than `""` is greater than `E`, so we can rewrite `h==E?A:B` into `h>E?B:A`.
- `h` is now a linked list where `3::2::1::nil` looks like `[3,[2,[1,[]]]]`, which exactly stringifies into `"3,2,1,"`. So we can simply coerce `h` to string: `t.s=_=>h+""`, or even better, `t.s=_=>h+E`.

#### Array unpacking

We can slightly do better here too:

```javascript
// instead of
t.o=_=>h>E?h[+!(h=h[1])]:N;
// do this
t.o=_=>h>E?([a,h]=h,a):N;
```

And this also applies to `t.e`:

```javascript
// instead of this
t.e=(i,l=h)=>h=l>E?[l[0],t.e(i,l[1])]:[i,E];
// do this
t.e=(i,[a,l]=h)=>h=l?[a,t.e(i,l)]:[i,E];
```

I chose `l?` because whenever `h` is nonempty, `l` is a reference so it always evaluates to true. If `h` is empty, both `a` and `l` become `undefined`.

Side note: I found that the OP's code actually works with falsy list items, because the only real comparison is `h==E`, that is, comparing <s>stringification</s> reference of whole array. Whatever `E` is, `h==E` cannot be true if the list `h` has at least one item, since <s>its string will have at least one more comma than `E`'s</s> the reference becomes different.

### Final result, <sub><s>125</s></sub> 121 bytes

```javascript
function L(){h=E=[];t=this;t.u=i=>h=[i,h];t.o=_=>h>E?([a,h]=h,a):null;t.e=(i,[a,l]=h)=>h=l?[a,t.e(i,l)]:[i,E];t.s=_=>h+E}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZHBbiIxDIbvPEU6p0SkdIAbkeE0txXStscRqkZTd5M2nawmSdEK5tmpAwMSpYvELfb/2/7svFWfla9b8zfcN@4Fd6@xqYNxDfvFxWYJTbRWFVAu5XKlAgRtvNJQqDCKYGCuoTRSkzJy8JxCKBbLmS6Hd1yDLscrkTQEbqQVSed2u9Ui2aiwWM3KQ6LMV5J8ZOvjvtKnrhsHWabW2lgyAI3iQmzcEMwwk1nXYohtw1zXnbMTJZQn5v/wzosFLyvKgJaVmO237XkpbSm9p7YLig58VhB0Qj/S6WHR7SwG9loR4AsD9sxgzjYs6NatWdG2ruVCsU4NkssaH8jT4DpRqsHg4YE9hap@HyRlFPlYqP41JXn/pIUZALAp2277MfyoRT75bpv8YDtq4yta2v5cPsGxtQmaBOv/MbT4gU04js9v5c2/2/IrTPnNvL8jRjwY8XRMvLzST5fAyx2uHXN6M9wjfmLr8fKvJ5dX9H2nbConciyz8261a7yzOLLuD8@eYl2j93cZCbsv)

Comment: Side side note: JavaScript compares arrays by reference, not by string. You're still right I think. You can verify this from the fact that `[1,1]==[1,1]` is false but `[1,1]+""==[1,1]+""` is true

Comment: *compares two arrays

Comment: why not `L=()=>{ * insert L's body here * }`

Comment: @famous1622 Because I have to provide a class, and you can't use `new` to create an instance of an arrow function. Furthermore, `this` in the arrow function would refer to `window` because arrow functions don't have their own scope